# xsl every row repeats instead of one row per customer

Tags: xml, xslt

Have an xml doc with xsl and .css.  I get the results but instead of getting one row per custID, I get one row each but each row has all of the customers in it.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.
---xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="html"
      doctype-system="about:legacy-compat"
      encoding="UTF-8"
      indent="yes" />

    <xsl:param name="customerID" select="//@custID"/>
   <xsl:variable name="reportCustomer" 
    select="document('customers.xml')/customers/customer[@custID=$customerID]" />

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
         <head>
            <title>Customer List</title>
            <link href="customersAgain.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
         </head>

         <body>
            <div id="wrap">

               <h1>Customers</h1>

<!-- <xsl:for-each select = "$customerID"> -->

               <table id="customerTable">
                  <tr>
                     <th>CustID</th>
                     <th>Cust FName</th>
                     <th>Cust LName</th>                     
                     <th>Address</th>
                     <th>Phone</th>
                     <th>Email</th>
                  </tr>
<xsl:for-each select = "$customerID">         
                  <tr>
                     <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$customerID" />
                     </td>               
                     <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$reportCustomer/first_name" />
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$reportCustomer/last_name" />
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$reportCustomer/street" /><br />
                        <xsl:value-of select="$reportCustomer/city" />, 
                        <xsl:value-of select="$reportCustomer/state" />
                        <xsl:value-of select="$reportCustomer/zip" />
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$reportCustomer/phone" />
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$reportCustomer/email" />
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="customers/customer[@custID=$customerID]" />
</xsl:for-each>               
               </table>

          <!--      <xsl:apply-templates select="customers/customer[@custID=$customerID]" />
</xsl:for-each> -->
             </div>
         </body>
      </html>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

----xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="customersAgain.xsl" ?>
<customers xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="customers.xsd">
    <customer custID = "cust10001">
        <first_name>Mina</first_name>
        <last_name>Talver</last_name>
        <street>1121 Huntington Road</street>
        <city>Morehead</city>
        <state>SD</state>
        <zip>52541</zip>
        <phone>(252) 123-8444</phone>
        <email>M.Talv@somenet.com</email>
    </customer>
    <customer custID = "cust10002">
        <first_name>Joe</first_name>
        <last_name>Crater</last_name>
        <street>526 Corona Lane</street>
        <city>Raleigh</city>
        <state>SC</state>
        <zip>52615</zip>
        <phone>(506) 123-5124</phone>
        <email>Jcray54@somenet.com</email>
    </customer>
    <customer custID = "cust10003">
        <first_name>Linda</first_name>
        <last_name>bigby</last_name>
        <street>74 Center Court</street>
        <city>Spaeder</city>
        <state>AL</state>
        <zip>85947</zip>
        <phone>(885) 123-5156</phone>
        <email>LinBig23@somenet.com</email>
    </customer>
    <customer custID = "cust10004">
        <first_name>Bradley</first_name>
        <last_name>Goetzman</last_name>
        <street>552 Walker Street</street>
        <city>Biloxy</city>
        <state>MA</state>
        <zip>52361</zip>
        <phone>(852) 123-2252</phone>
        <email>Bradgoesgreen54@somenet.com</email>
    </customer>
    <customer custID = "cust10005">
        <first_name>Donna</first_name>
        <last_name>Lipsky</last_name>
        <street>954 Mannard Way</street>
        <city>Carhart</city>
        <state>FL</state>
        <zip>52398</zip>
        <phone>(954) 123-6251</phone>
        <email>DonnaLip565@somenet.com</email>
    </customer>
    <customer custID = "cust10006">
        <first_name>Heath</first_name>
        <last_name>Braden</last_name>
        <street>58 East State Street</street>
        <city>Silo Rapids</city>
        <state>MN</state>
        <zip>52632</zip>
        <phone>(232) 123-8545</phone>
        <email>HeBraden56@somenet.com</email>
    </customer>
    <customer custID = "cust10007">
        <first_name>Charisma</first_name>
        <last_name>Wingard</last_name>
        <street>45 Beverly Way</street>
        <city>Paris</city>
        <state>TX</state>
        <zip>75858</zip>
        <phone>(856) 123-7458</phone>
        <email>CharWingard83@somenet.com</email>
    </customer>
    <customer custID = "cust10008">
        <first_name>Drake</first_name>
        <last_name>Sorento</last_name>
        <street>332 Kia Street</street>
        <city>Carrito</city>
        <state>NM</state>
        <zip>55636</zip>
        <phone>(864) 123-4565</phone>
        <email>DaSorento21@somenet.com</email>
    </customer>
    <customer custID = "cust10009">
        <first_name>Jessica</first_name>
        <last_name>Denon</last_name>
        <street>562 Arthur Circle</street>
        <city>Oak Tree</city>
        <state>WY</state>
        <zip>88787</zip>
        <phone>(123) 123-5262</phone>
        <email>DenonJ4545@somenet.com</email>
    </customer>
    <customer custID = "cust10010">
        <first_name>Becky</first_name>
        <last_name>Newton</last_name>
        <street>45 North Avenue</street>
        <city>Capitulo</city>
        <state>TX</state>
        <zip>55698</zip>
        <phone>(415) 123-5445</phone>
        <email>NewBecky232@somenet.com</email>
    </customer>
    <customer custID = "cust10011">
        <first_name>Rodger</first_name>
        <last_name>Comancho</last_name>
        <street>852 Leaf Boulevard</street>
        <city>Warren</city>
        <state>OK</state>
        <zip>63589</zip>
        <phone>(777) 123-2052</phone>
        <email>ComanR43@somenet.com</email>
    </customer>
    <customer custID = "cust10012">
        <first_name>Mike</first_name>
        <last_name>Doger</last_name>
        <street>63 willingsway Drive</street>
        <city>Saint Aug</city>
        <state>CA</state>
        <zip>36258</zip>
        <phone>(121) 123-1221</phone>
        <email>MikeDoger134@somenet.com</email>
    </customer>
</customers>
```

Looking for results as:

```
CustID      Cust FName  Cust LName  Address                           Phone     Email
cust10001   Mina        Talver      1121 Huntington Road, Morehead, SD 52541  (252) 123-8444  M.Talv@somenet.com

cust10002   Joe   Crater  526 Corona Lane, Raleigh, SC  52615  (506) 123-5124  Jcray54@somenet.com
```

and so on
Hope someone can help!  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$reportCustomer/first_name" />
```

to:

```
<xsl:value-of select="../first_name" />
```

and so on. Otherwise you're starting from the root of the `$reportCustomer` document and selecting all `first_name` nodes. Use a relative path to the current customer's data instead.

---

P.S. I am not sure what the condition in `customer[@custID=$customerID]` is supposed to accomplish - it seems to me it will always be true. Or why you need to use the `document()` function, instead of working directly with the XML input.

Also, this line does not makes sense (and luckily does not do anything else either), at least not in the context of `@custID`:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="customers/customer[@custID=$customerID]" />
```

I think you could simplify your stylesheet to something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 

<xsl:template match="/customers"> 
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Customer List</title>
            <link href="customersAgain.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="wrap">
                <h1>Customers</h1>
                <table id="customerTable">
                    <tr>
                        <th>CustID</th>
                        <th>Cust FName</th>
                        <th>Cust LName</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <th>Phone</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="customer"> 
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@custID" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="first_name" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="last_name" />
                            </td>
                            <td> 
                                <xsl:value-of select="street" />
                                <br />
                                <xsl:value-of select="city" />
                                <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                                <xsl:value-of select="state" />
                                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                                <xsl:value-of select="zip" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="phone" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="email" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each> 
                </table>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```